# Difference between two forms of benzothiadiazole

Tags: organic-chemistry, cheminformatics

Can someone please advise / point me to information regarding the difference between these two compounds:

https://www.combi-blocks.com/cgi-bin/find.cgi?HC-3087

[image]

https://www.combi-blocks.com/cgi-bin/find.cgi?JH-8440

[image]

The reason for this question is that [rdkit](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/index.html) assigns them the same 'inchikey', as if they were identical, or spontaneously interconverting substances (like tautomers).
But they aren't tautomers, as there is no atom being transferred, only electrons; and they are distinct commercial substances, sold in fairly large quantities, so I would guess they are individually sufficiently stable.

Many variously decorated commercial compounds containing either of these moieties are also found, reinforcing the above conclusion.

So it would seem that the machinery that calculates the inchikey is wrong in treating these two molecules as identical.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT** summary of insights from the comments

According to both the people who commented so far, these two species are resonance structures of the same molecule.
The fact that different cas numbers, names, catalogue numbers from a single vendor are found for the two, would therefore seem to be incorrect, misleading and unjustified.
On the contrary, the fact that rdkit returns the same inchikey for the two seems to be correct.

Comment: Just learn to draw mesomeric structures, instead of using some "combi-blocks" - the second one has one bond too many.

Comment: Both structures have the same atom-to-atom connectivity (including H atoms) and the same formula of C6H4N2S.  Both rings of 2,1,3-benzathiadiazole are aromatic.  I think these are two resonance structures of the same compound.

Comment: Do you really think the two sulfur atoms in https://www.dougdiscovery.com/4-8-dibromobenzo-1-2-c-4-5-c-bis-1-2-5-thiadiazole.html are chemically distinguishable?

Comment: @Mithoron - surprising though it may sound to you, I do know how to draw chemical structures. I used the pictures from the vendor to show how *they* represented these molecules. And FYI, Scifinder (CAS) also draws these two molecules in the exact same way as Combi-Blocks does. If you have more information to provide, please do so. It is not really clear to me how making such snide comments or insinuations about people's intelligence or skills helps answering the question I am asking.

Comment: @CurtF. - that's what I thought, too, based on the principle that when only electrons are moving, we are talking about resonance, not tautomerism or anything that changes the identity of the molecule. But then how is it possible that the two species (and many derivatives) are represented as distinct, and sold with different catalogue numbers in vendors websites, described with different synthesis in papers, etc? BTW, we also need to establish if the representations here are both at least formally correct, because apparently someone (see note above) thinks one of the two is wrong.

Comment: Sorry for sounding harsh, but it boils down just to the knowledge about resonance (not intelligence, as you mentioned), Some structure drawing tools are just tools, users need to discern if results are good or not (they frequently aren't). In this case a slightly alleviating factor could be people buying into deprecated hypervalency - this second mesomeric structure is the "hypervalent" one. Also how some vendors draw it and sell, isn't exactly relevant, apparently can lead rather to confusion than to learning.

Comment: Could you link to some of those distinct syntheses from papers?  And also, just because there are two resonance structures, doesn't mean that both are equally prevalent.  I like the structure without the hypervalent sulfur better.

Comment: @Mithoron - well, I came here to discuss a scientific matter. You can choose to help or to make assumptions about my knowledge. On topic: 1) you still have not explained why you stated that the second structure is not correct. It is represented like that in Scifinder, as I mentioned. 2) as I wrote in my reply to CurtF., I too was initially inclined to think that these were equivalent molecules, given the identical inchikey etc, but came to to doubt my conclusion when vendors, scientific papers and Scifinder seemed to differentiate them. I cannot think of many examples where that happens.

Comment: I did say this structure is hypervalent, more precisely sulfur atom in there is, and hypervalency is a deprecated concept. Either way it's definitely just an additional mesomeric structure, definitely not a separate compound. Now I wonder if it would be even physically possible to be otherwise...

Comment: "the second one has one bond too many" - has it, really?

Comment: @Curt F. : Scifinder reports 125 references where the 1st molecule is a product. Example: "1,2,5-Thiadiazole 2-oxides: selective synthesis, structural characterization, and electrochemical properties" Konstantinova, Lidia S.; et al
Tetrahedron (2014), 70(35), 5558-5568. And it reports 8 references where the 2nd molecule is a product. Example: "Reactions of arylthiazylamides with internal and external fluoro electrophiles - formation of products with unusual structures" Lork, Enno; et al
European Journal of Inorganic Chemistry (2001), (8), 2123-2134.

Comment: Overall, the information you guys provided was useful and made me conclude what I mentioned in the edit. In essence, I should have trusted the fundamental principles of chemistry more than registry numbers, catalogue numbers, etc. I see people are voting to close this question. Please do so; or I can I will do it myself. Let's put everyone out of their misery. General comment on how this went: it would just be nice if people learned to exchange ideas without resorting to insults and condescendence. It does not reflect well on scientist when the only mode of communication they know is spite.

Comment: For the record: "Homework questions must demonstrate some effort to understand the underlying concepts." was the reason people provided for closing the question.
*Wrong*. The _very first thing_ that I did was research these two substances, draw myself the resonance structures to see how they were conceptually the same (one electron pair from the S atom of the first one can be moved to the ring, all other pairs shift around until the last one reconnects to S, forming the N=S=N moiety).
I should have stopped at that and ignored the other misleading evidence pointing to them being different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In practice, there is no difference between the two structures - they represent the same compound if you were to purchase them. That said, in terms of "correctness", the non-hypervalent structure is preferred, even though its Lewis structure still does not accurately represent the full electronic structure of the molecule. You could add some non-hypervalent charge-separated resonance forms which improve the description, as shown below.

[image]

The overarching truth is that occasionally you can find compounds with unusual Lewis structures available for purchase because they weren't sanity-checked. This is especially likely with combinatorial chemistry suppliers as they will often automatically populate their catalogues with thousands of structures. For example, sometimes you can find a cyclohexa-2,4-diene-1-one on offering, though on further inspection a chemist would realize these are actually a phenol tautomer, which typically only exist in part-per-trillion amounts.

But with benzothiadiazole specifically, the problem goes a bit deeper. While a trivial and satisfying Lewis structure can be assigned to it (or more precisely, benzo[c][1,2,5]thiadiazole), what about the related structure benzobis(thiadiazole) (more precisely, benzo[1,2-c:4,5-c']bis([1,2,5]thiadiazole)), which contains another fused benzothiadiazole ring opposite to the first? This is a well-known compound, of which hundreds of variants have been explored in organic electronics.

It turns out in this case that there is no "trivial" Lewis structure which can be assigned to the compound, at least not without a hypervalent sulfur atom. And curiously, *that's what the literature has settled on* - a quick Google image search of benzobisthiadiazole will turn up dozens of articles using the hypervalent structure shown below. It has become the standard in the field, and nobody particularly cares. It **is** possible to draw a non-hypervalent charge-separated resonance form, but it is ignored. The true electronic structure is even more complex, apparently including non-negligible biradicaloid character, which *can* be shown on a non-hypervalent Lewis structure.

[image]

As a last point, x-ray crystallographic data of benzobisthiadiazole compounds show that the two thiadiazole rings are typically completely equivalent (there is no single hypervalent ring, as the widely-drawn structures suggest), indicating that it really all boils down to Lewis structures just being limited tools at representing reality. You always have a trade-off between simplicity of representation and accuracy, and sometimes this trade-off is particularly unsatisfying.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much for this detailed explanation! "occasionally you can find compounds with unusual Lewis structures available for purchase because they weren't sanity-checked" - that's quite bad indeed, but while one may forgive _vendors_ for not being so strict with their checks, it remains shocking (to me) to find _distinct cas numbers_ for species that do not even exist individually. I created a post about that. The phenol vs cyclohexadienone example is not strictly applicable: tautomers are indeed _distinct species_ with, as you point out, measurable proportions in mixtures.